# Como recuperar campos calculados no Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Meu controller edit

```
$tipos     = TituloTipo::all();
$devedores = Devedor::all();
$clientes  = Cliente::all();
$divida    = Divida::find($id);

return view('admin.dividas.edit',compact('divida','devedores','clientes', 'tipos'  ));
```

> Na tabela Dívida necessito que sempre que o usuário editar, vizualizar o campo total_corrigido seja atualizado para uma fórmula de juros simples.
>   total_corrigido = valor_divida x juros x meses

Comment: `total_corrigido` é um campo da sua tabela? se sim com eventos você pode resolver isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma é usar um accessor

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
class Divida extends Model
{
    /**
     * obter total da dívida.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTotalCorrigidoAttribute()
    {
        return $this->valor_divida x $this->juros x $this->meses;
    }
}

$divida  = Divida::find($id);

//view

<p>O valor da dívida é {{$divida->total_corrigido}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A princípio, o que você precisará fazer é recuperar o campo em específico da sua Model:

```
$tipos     = TituloTipo::all();
$devedores = Devedor::all();
$clientes  = Cliente::all();
$divida    = Divida::find($id);
$dividaAtualizada = $divida['valor_divida'] * $juros * date_diff(date_create(date('m')), date_create($data_ini))->format('%d');
return view('admin.dividas.edit',compact('divida','devedores','clientes', 'tipos', 'dividaAtualizada'  ));
```

Recomendo que o cálculo seja feita através de uma função. a variável $data_ini você precisará ver como irá recuperar do seu banco de dados (pelo formato como foi cadastrado, etc).